# How to Join 2 Tables using Server-Side Processing DataTables

Tags: php, sql, join, datatable

Index.php HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#users').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "server_processing.php"
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Server Side DataTable</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="users" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Fist Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Location</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Server Script

```
$table = 'users';
$primaryKey = 'id';


$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id',          'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'first_name',        'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',     'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'phone',    'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'site',    'dt' => 4 ),
);


// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => 'datatables',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

  require( 'ssp.class.php' );

  echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns)

  );
```

Database Tables

users

```
id| first_name| last_name| phone| site|
--- ---------- ---------- ------ ------
1   Barry       Roux      0454554   1
2   Sylvester   Gus       012124    2
```

sites

```
id| name
--- ---------- 
1   London    
2   Edinburgh
```

Desired Output

```
ids| name| surname |     number|    location
--- ------   ----         -------   ------
1   Barry       Roux      0454554   London
2   Sylvester   Gus       012124    Edinburgh
```

The Above Code Shows a basic example of how to get records from One single Table (users) using server side datatable. 
Now I would like to Join and show records from 2 Tables. using something like this Query :

```
SELECT u.id as ids, u.first_name as name , u.last_name as surname, u.phone as number , s.name as location
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN sites s ON s.id = u.site.
```

Any idea how I can do that ?
Please Help

Answer (score 3):

You've probably solved it by now... But (like me) others may come across this question, and I found a solution!

Here it is: https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-using-where-join-and-group-by-with-ssp-class-php/

You will need to edit the `ssp.class.php`. Find and replace all the and replace FROM `$table' with FROM $table (removing the back-ticks).

```
<?php

$table = <<<EOT
 (
    SELECT
      a.id,
      a.name,
      b.position
    FROM table a
    LEFT JOIN positions b ON a.position_id = b.id
 ) temp
EOT;

$primaryKey = 'id';

$columns = array(
   array( 'db' => 'id',          'dt' => 0 ),
   array( 'db' => 'name',        'dt' => 1 ),
   array( 'db' => 'position',    'dt' => 2 )
);

$sql_details = array(
   'user' => '',
   'pass' => '',
   'db'   => '',
   'host' => ''
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
   SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

All credit goes to Michael Ryvkin.

Comment: I tried the answer above and continually get a PHP syntax error - unexpected '<<'

Answer (score 0):

**create view in mysql** and use view name in $table variable like
$table = 'users_data_view'; in you server script i.e ajax_json.php file

view structure 
CREATE VIEW users_data_view AS select_join_query_goes_here

in mysql run this below sql command(and replace "select_join_query_goes_here" with your select query if you want) for create new view

```
CREATE VIEW users_data_view AS SELECT u.id as ids, u.first_name as name , u.last_name as surname, u.phone as number , s.name as location
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN sites s ON s.id = u.site
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using https://github.com/emran/ssp as an alternative to ssp.class.php. I personally found it hard and impossible to work with ssp.class.php in joining tables.